# How can I make the window buttons in the panel match the window buttons in the window decorations?

Tags: 11.04, unity, customization, appearance

When the Ambiance GTK theme is selected in Applications ▸ Appearance ▸ Customize ▸ Controls, the window buttons in the panel match the window buttons of the Ambiance Metacity theme's window decorations:

[image: Ambiance GTK theme]

When I choose any other GTK theme (e.g. Dust) in Applications ▸ Appearance ▸ Customize ▸ Controls, the window buttons in the panel change to something I do not recognize:

[image: Equinox GTK theme]

These strange, off-center window buttons are inconsistent with the current window decorations (Ambiance):

[image: Equinox GTK theme]

How can I either

- switch back to the Ambiance-compatible window buttons in the panel while still using non-Ambiance controls, or
- alter the images that Unity uses to make the strange, off-center window buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buttons for light themes are hard coded into Unity. Support for metacity themes has not landed yet in Unity. There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/740232) filed on LP too. Hope fully, proper support will be added in Oneiric.

You could modify images found in /usr/share/unity to achieve some level of customizability, I suppose.