# position of window control buttons

Tags: unity, compiz, metacity

can we have unity move the max/min/close buttons to the right?

When the window is not maximized, Metacity takes control of the window, therefore we can use gconf-editor to force the traditional min/max/close right style buttons.

However, when Compiz takes control (maximized), it's back to Ubuntu style.
Any way to make Compiz obey gconf-editor or an option in the Unity plugin?

Comment: **Welcome to AskUbuntu!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unity doesn't follow these gconf rules, and in fact there is a different decorator being used (it doesn't draw the window controls in the unity panel).

This is an often requested feature though.

See these questions for more details:

- [How can I make the window buttons in the panel match the window buttons in the window decorations?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36706/1992)
- [Can the Close / Minimize / Maximize buttons be pulled out of the Global App Menu when a window is maximized?](https://askubuntu.com/q/39040/1992)
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/775346

Comment: I know Compiz and Metacity's differences ;) As stated in Question

Thanks for the links though, I'll keep an eye on the current activity!

Comment: @rxu the real difference is between unity-window-decorator,  gtk-window-decorator, and the unity-panel not between compiz and metacity.